# Generating a pattern from user-defined rules

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I want to generate a list of $L$ and $S$ according to the following rule: 
 upon each iteration, replace

- $S \rightarrow L$
- $L \rightarrow LS$

Such that, starting with $L$:

### $ L \rightarrow LS \rightarrow LSL \rightarrow LSLLS \rightarrow LSLLSLSL \rightarrow LSLLSLSLLSLLS \rightarrow \dots$

How can I automate this with Mathematica? I just want to specify the starting letter and the number of iteration and I'd want it to spit out the final result.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the 5th iterate:

```
Nest[
 Replace[#, {L -> Sequence[L, S], S -> Sequence[L]}, {1}] &,
 {L},
 5
 ]
```

> {L, S, L, L, S, L, S, L, L, S, L, L, S}

And for the list of first 5 iterates:

```
NestList[
 Replace[#, {L -> Sequence[L, S], S -> Sequence[L]}, {1}] &,
 {L},
 5
 ]
```

> {{L}, {L, S}, {L, S, L}, {L, S, L, L, S}, {L, S, L, L, S, L, S, 
>     L}, {L, S, L, L, S, L, S, L, L, S, L, L, S}}

**Edit:**

`SubstitutionSystem` operates on strings instead. It is a bit faster because it is specifically designed for [Lindenmayer systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system):

```
L = "L";
S = "S";
a = StringJoin /@ NestList[
      Replace[#, {L -> Sequence[L, S], S -> Sequence[L]}, {1}] &,
      {L},
      20
      ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
b = SubstitutionSystem[{"L" -> "LS", "S" -> "L"}, "L", 20]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

a == b
```

> 0.004506
>
> 0.001265
>
> True

PS.: As Carl Woll pointed out, the following will return only the 20th iterate.

```
c = SubstitutionSystem[{"L" -> "LS", "S" -> "L"}, "L", {20}];
```

Comment: What if I just wanted a random sequence of $L$ and $S$?

Comment: Then you can use `RandomChoice`: `RandomChoice[{L, S}, {10000}]` will generate a list of `10000` random letter at once (uniformly distributed). You can also prescribe probabilities for each letter, e.g. `RandomChoice[{0.1, 0.9} -> {L, S}, 10000]`.

Comment: Great, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: @SuperCiocia Please forget what I said about `SequenceReplace`. Better use `Replace` with level specification `{1}`. That does also not suffer from using symbols.

Comment: FYI I thanks you on Physcs SE where I used your code, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/427330/quasiperiodicity-of-the-fibonacci-chain/429120#429120. Thanks again.

Comment: If the user were only interested in the twentieth iterate, they could use {20} instead of 20.

Comment: Good point! Thanks, I will mention that in the answer.

Answer (score 13):

You may use [`ReplaceRepeated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html)with its [`MaxIterations`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxIterations.html)option.

```
ReplaceRepeated[{L}, {L -> Sequence[L, S], S -> Sequence[L]}, 
 MaxIterations -> 5]
```

> ```
> {L, S, L, L, S, L, S, L, L, S, L, L, S}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

A recursive method:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[L] = Sequence[L, S];
f[S] = L;
f[a__, b_] := f[a, b] = Sequence[f @ a, f @ b]

List @ Nest[f, L, 7]
```

> {L, S, L, L, S, L, S, L, L, S, L, L, S, L, S, L, L, S, L, S, L, L, S, 
>   L, L, S, L, S, L, L, S, L, L, S}